# Make Ionic Native Camera Plugin only take pictures from FRONT camera

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

My current options for taking photos from an iPad camera in my Ionic/Cordova application are as follows:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 70,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true,
        cameraDirection: this.camera.Direction.FRONT
    };
```

I read on the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/camera/parameter/cameraOptions.html) that setting the property cameraDirection tells which camera you want to use when you take a picture on a device using your app. I set the direction to front, hoping this would mean that only front facing pictures would be accepted. Unfortunately, I am still able to switch to my back camera once the camera app is opened.

Is there a way to limit the camera to only being used by the front facing camera?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not with Cordova, because the Camera plugin uses a native camera from the device that always includes the rotation button. You can however [create a custom camera](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#custom-camera) plugin (in Java) to get rid of all buttons but this requires plenty of Java knowledge.